# Disadvantages of separating code corresponding to independent blocks with different namespace rather than a different project in the same solution

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am working on a project in which my entire team is facing the following problem, please help me to discover the issues associated with the approach which we have decided to follow so that we can save ourselves beforehand :)

We have decided to separate out the entire code of our application into just three projects in a single solution.

1) One project will contain entire UI
2) Second will contain entire business logic. In this project the code corresponding to different modules of our application will be separated via different namespaces rahter than having separate project for each modules or dependent modules.
3) The third project will contain all the common code

I am still able to see that there might be some problem in future if we put the entire code in second project under different namespaces in a single dll rather that splitting it in different dlls/projects.
We are working on a WPF based application.

Please help!

Shahil Gautam

Answer (score 2):

> I am still able to see that there might be some problem in future if we put the entire code in second project under different namespaces in a single dll rather that splitting it in different dlls/projects. We are working on a WPF based application.

The only "problem" with doing this is that it's a bit easier to "accidentally" reference types in other namespaces.  If you separate into separate projects, the only way to "pollute" your type with business logic unrelated to it would be to explicitly add a reference.  When it's in the same project, you can have a using statement or a fully qualified type name, and "use" an unrelated type without any compiler warnings.

Comment: Good SoC begins with project references.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's a sensible choice. I general, assemblies should be units of deployment. There is no need to have 10 assemblies if they are always going to be deployed together.

One issue however is that you will have to be more careful about your dependencies within a project. When separating things into different projects, there are physical barriers for introducing inappropriate dependencies, while now you will have to be more conscious about this. A tool like [ndepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) might help you find suspicious dependencies in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why you would want to have multiple namespaces within your business logic project.

There are two possibilities:

ONE. All of the types that you define in the project have different unqualified names.

In this case, separating the namespaces would have little purpose. The only benifit would be that the intellisense object selections would be shorter and clearer when the usings to the other namespaces are omitted. Putting the types into separate projects would accomplish the same thing just as well, and offer better separation of concerns.

TWO. Some of the types in the different namespaces have the same unqualified names.

In this case, confusion could easily result, whenever a `using` from another namespace is added in an unsuccessful attempt to reference a type from another namespace with its unqualified name. If there is no danger of that happening, then, once again, why not put the objects into separate projects, since, clearly, the lines between the domains are sharply drawn?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your expert comments guys!

Comment: I have few more questions: Apart from increasing the chance of polluting the code and confusion in later development stages, 1) Does this approach also involves increased build time of the project when there are changes only in the code specific to one module/block. I mean to say that will the application build(not rebuild) quickly if I use different project rather than putting everything in same project under different namespaces. 2) We have opted this approach to get rid of circular dependency problem, is it wise to do so or should we still consider taking out independent stuff

Comment: @Shahil Gautam - If the project is so large that build times are a problem, then I would definitely consider separating it into projects. That will improve the build times, since only the portions of the program that change will need to be rebuilt.

Comment: @Shahil Gautam - The circular dependency problem is best delt with by creating interfaces that can be referenced by all the projects, and then supplying concrete instantiations of those interfaces to each object that needs them when each object is created in the higher layers of the application.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeffrey L Whitledge, I think it will really help me a lot!

Comment: Namespaces are useful as documentation and if you were to use a tool like NDepend, you can visualize dependencies between them. I prefer to follow the Java way of associating namespaces with the folder structure. This also helps new developers more quickly pick up the flow of the program and if you group features roughly into namespaces, you only need to look at a small collection of files in a folder. It also works very great with intellisense to keep the noise down. Why do you think there are so many namespaces in the SDK?

Comment: @Christo - I just think that if your project is so large that it would benifit from multiple namespaces, then it should probably be broken up into mulitple projects. This would also imply separate folders and namespaces. It also makes dependencies explicit, which is stronger than simply visualizing them. This helps with enforcing the logical structure of the program. I am arguing for more structure—not less.